# Break for loop inside a web request (in swift)

Tags: swift, for-loop, ios8, break

Inside my for loop i run a web request. Now if theres an error in the web request i want to break the for loop, however i get this error:
`break is only allowed inside a loop or switch` I've also tried naming my for loop like I've seen such as `myLoopName : for(...)` then calling it with `break myLoopName` but then i get the same error.

Here is an example of how my code looks currently

```
myLoopName : for(...) {
...
SRWebClient.POST(someUrlString)
.data(...)
.send({(response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in
    //process success response
},failure:{(error:NSError!) -> Void in
    //process failure response
    println(error)
    //where break must occur
})
}
```

How do i break the loop inside a web request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it using a function when dealing with closures and breaks:

```
func loop() {
    SRWebClient.POST(someUrlString).data().send( { response, status in
        loop()
    },
    failure:{ (error:NSError!) -> Void in
        println(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Great idea, i might try that next time. For me just using return instead of break worked.

Answer (score 1):

I used `return` instead of `break` and it worked perfectly

```
func loop() {
    SRWebClient.POST(someUrlString).data().send( { response, status in
        loop()
    },
    failure:{ (error:NSError!) -> Void in
        println(error)
        return
    }
}
```